# concat using rest parameters in es6, javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Complete function that convertTemplate() which takes rest parameters as input 
and returns a concatenated string as input irrespective of the 
data type passed as argument to the function.

```
sample input - convertTemplate('aa',3)
output : aa3
*/

let convertTemplate = (...input)=>{

};
```

Comment: And what do you have so far?

Comment: This appears to be a class assignment or interview question. Please show that you've made some effort at solving this question before coming here. Show your best attempt, even if it didn't work, and explain what went wrong (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method since `input` is an array. Although, [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method will [convert all elements into a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Description) internally and joined.

```js
let convertTemplate = (...input) => input.join('')

console.log(convertTemplate('aa', 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let convertTemplate = (...input)=>{
  return Array.from(input).join("");
};

console.log(convertTemplate('aa',3));
```